# Divi theme including javascript

Tags: themes, javascript, child-theme

I have tested the html and the css and the js independently of wordpress and all works fine.  So trying to integrate it into wordpress.  I have added the html code as a code module.  I have created a folder in the main theme dir (not the child) called 'js' and have included the following into the `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_assets' ); 

function my_enqueue_assets() { 

    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' ); 
    wp_register_script( 'portfolio', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/portfolio.js', '', null,''  );
    wp_register_script( 'index', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/index.js', '', null,''  );
    wp_register_script( 'config', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/config.js', '', null,''  );

    wp_register_script( 'jquery.colorbox-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js', '', null,''  );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.colorbox-min' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'portfolio' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'index' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'config' );
}
```

I am not sure if this code is correct but hope that someone can give me some advice on why it doesn't work.

Comment: If you use child theme, why you create folder in main theme?

Comment: i just wanted to have a look , i have the same js folder in both child and parent now to test... any ideas ?

Comment: **why it doesn't work** Is always the hard question. Narrow down the problem by specifying, do you see scripts in page source? URLs are correct? Or you do not see at all ?

Comment: urls correct , is the code above syntax correct ???

Comment: yes , using a divi theme on my webspace , have child and parent , the above code is the functions.php file , the javascript files are also on both child and parent locations now so confused , the above code is not right for some reason but not sure why

Comment: could be the last parameter of `wp_register_script`, default is 'all' and you are setting to blank... plus, an aside: you should add the dependency `array('jquery')` to the third paramater for colorbox (and any other script that needs jquery)

Comment: @havingagoatit 1. Please merge your accounts http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts 2. Your code do not have any error. You must test with default theme.

Comment: i dont understand , i have only the divi theme

Comment: can someone post the code that does not have the mistake as I am not sure with php

Comment: Then download twenty fifteen and test the same. Your code do no have any single error at all.

Comment: just to check you your child theme is actually active..? you still have not answered anyone as to whether you are getting *any* output in the page source or not...

Comment: the only output is the html code that i loaded into a 'code module' in wp-admin   .... the css seems to also be working

Comment: so the above code is correct, the html and css are also correct, and the js is in the js folder.... what on earth could be wrong ?

Comment: maybe i should use a javascript autoload plugin to simply load the files from there ? what do you guys think

Comment: @havingagoatit  First merge your accounts http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: why do i have to merge accounts ? it is only the divi theme

Comment: Because you can not have two accounts! If it is only not working with divi theme it off-topic so please test with default theme, then only someone can help. We are not gating paid to solve issues related divi theme.

Comment: ah right , ok , im not using child theme any more , will stick to main divi theme functions.php this was maybe the problem , i will work from just divi theme now

Comment: ok so the main functions.php file is HUUUGE .... i tried to add the code above on the end of the page and it crahes the site ... ?

Comment: Ok , I have used a plugin called 'Javascript Autoloader' and it has seen the js files so i now know that the js files are being loaded

Comment: downvoted as it is not clear what is the question at all, and probably of topic as it strongly relates to divi

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) instead of `get_template_directory_uri()` when you're referencing files in a child theme.

On a fresh install, I created and activated a child theme of `twentyfifteen` called `child` and run the following codes:

```
echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); 
# Output: http://localhost/test1/wp-content/themes/child

echo get_template_directory_uri(); 
# Output: http://localhost/test1/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen
```

Also, If you have tested the JS independently of WordPress, you should know that WordPress loads jQuery in the no conflict mode, that is, you should use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

So:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // JS code
});
```

Becomes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // JS code
});
```